# Error while packaging application - Flex ANE

Tags: apache-flex, package, air-native-extension, ane

We are integrating Push notification with AppBoy SDK in our Flex project.
We are created ANE but while packaging application got error like this

Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKDevice.o)
"_CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont", referenced from:
  -[ABKInAppMessageViewController applyIconToLabelView:] in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKInAppMessageViewController.o)
"_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
  +[ABKFacebookDataProvider facebookAccountExistsInIOS] in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
  ___85+[ABKFacebookDataProvider fetchAndPostFacebookDataAccessPromptWithSuccessCompletion:]_block_invoke in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
  +[ABKFacebookDataProvider fetchAndPostFacebookDataAccessPromptWithSuccessCompletion:] in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
  +[ABKFacebookDataProvider fetchAndPostFacebookDataAccessPromptWithSuccessCompletion:] in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
  +[ABKFacebookDataProvider fetchAndPostFacebookDataAccessPromptWithSuccessCompletion:] in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libcom.fingent.appboyapn.a(ABKFacebookDataProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your ANE been recompiled to 64bit from old 32bit xcode compile? If not you need to do this to compile w Apache Flex SDK above 16 (check doc for exact version...) Someplace on this site is a nifty ANT compiler that I used once: http://easynativeextensions.com/making-your-ios-apps-universal/ Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved this. This is the problem with frameworks. By default AIR support some frameworks. If we are using any other frameworks we need to package it while creating ANE.

[Please refer this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7fff.html)